# Ошибка android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dagger2, context

Уважаемые люди я запустил context в класс Callback вот так:

```
class Callback @Inject constructor(
    private val context: Context, // gonna be error???
    private val database: Provider<WordDatabase>,
    @ApplicationScope private val applicationScope: CoroutineScope
) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
```

и получил ошибку:

```
Dagger/MissingBinding] android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

Файл appModule:

```
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(
        app: Application,
        callback: WordDatabase.Callback
    ) = Room.databaseBuilder(app, WordDatabase::class.java, "word_database")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .addCallback(callback)
        .build()

    @Provides
    fun provideWordDao(db: WordDatabase) = db.wordDao()

    @ApplicationScope
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplicationScopre() = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())

}

// part 4
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
annotation class ApplicationScope
```

Не подскажете что где нужно приписать чтобы Context запустить в колбек без ошибки?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как следует из текста ошибки, Dagger не смог запровайдить `Context`, так как не смог найти метод, где он провайдится. Скорее всего вы используете не просто Dagger, а Hilt. Hilt по умолчанию может провайдить `Context`. Но так как объект типа `Context` может быть как контекстом `Application`, так и контекстом `Acitvity`, Dagger не может заинжектить его без квалификатора. Просто добавьте аннотацию `@ApplicationContext` к параметру в конструкторе и Dagger сможет найти его:

```
class Callback @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext private val context: Context,
    private val database: Provider<WordDatabase>,
    @ApplicationScope private val applicationScope: CoroutineScope
) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
```

Вторым вариантом будем вместо `Context` сделать в конструкторе параметр типа `Application`, так как в `Callback` вам нужен `Context` приложения, а `Application` как раз наследует `Context`:

```
class Callback @Inject constructor(
        private val context: Application,
        private val database: Provider<WordDatabase>,
        @ApplicationScope private val applicationScope: CoroutineScope
    ) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
```